# Hostname spans over different namespaces with traefik?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have the following scenario and ask myself what the best solution could be:

Namespace **a** serves "example.com" using Traefik ingress.

Namespace **b** is suppost to only serve "example.com/mypath" using Traefik ingress.

So far, there is an external service configured in namespace **a** and a route created that proxies the traffic on /mypath to Namespace **b** but this feels hacky.

Ideally, there would be no dependency in deployments.

Is there a way to deploy both namespaces independently, eg: only solve it using the Traefik ingress in front?

Comment: on nginx ingress you should use 2 separated ingress files. i guess same applies to traefik. if it is, i'd like to show you how